# MiniProfiler results UI shows empty names since using SqlServerStorage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

We have been using MiniProfiler as a simple way to profile our ASP.NET MVC 5 application performance.  It worked well in dev, but as soon as we put the application into staging on a web farm, we soon realised we needed to use a different/shared storage medium.

We migrated to SqlServerStorage by putting

`MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDb"].ConnectionString)`

into `MvcApplication.Application_Start` (Global.asax)

We created the MiniProfiler tables using the script in `StackExchange.Profiling.Storage.SqlServerStorage.TableCreationScript`.

Since using SqlServerStorage, we have found that the MiniProfiler UI no longer functions properly; we get the following:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the name column is empty.  Anyone any ideas whether I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in MiniProfiler v4 (currently in alpha). Unfortunately, v3 did not store the `Name` field in SQL Server. It's [listed as a breaking change in the upgrade notes](http://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/UpgradeFromV3) since it requires [a schema addition](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/commit/2e1ca59b459de98a6ac8fe039166ab42bde23718). I couldn't make this change in v3 *because* it was a breaking change.

Look for MiniProfiler v4 to exit alpha in the next few weeks as we dogfood it heavily in production and advance to beta and release.